# angular, nested repeat breaking directive (packery + dragabilly)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, packery

I am having a slight issue with using dragabilly in angular, the problem is odd because it was working until I made some changes to how the content using packery is loaded in, specifically adding a level of nested repeats. When I do this, packery still runs correctly, however it seems dragabilly only runs on the first object.

The html looks like -

```
 <div class="item gs-w" ng-class="widget.size" ng-repeat="widget in contentHere" packery-angular >
    <!-- nested repeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="side in widget.sides" ng-show="side.active">
```

So it's just a nested repeat where packery runs off of the outer items, and again, the packery element works fine. It broke when I Added in the nested repeat - these objects have multiple faces which I hide with that side.acive you see there, however the drag handle is inside the nested repeat and I think this may be the problem, or perhaps the nested is taking a bit longer to load in and it doesn't recognize the handle in time? I'm not too sure and that's where I could use some direction.

Here is the directive - http://jsfiddle.net/yq4zwLzs/ . The only thing I added to it was that mobile UA check to try and turn off dragabilly on mobile devices because it's unnecessary at that point. I Tried taking that off it doesn't seem to effect anything.

Here is a plunker of it in action -

http://plnkr.co/edit/HSVztH3vlf5VI1lf1tFR?p=preview

Forgive the ugliness - but if you look, you can move around the top item, but not the bottom item. That is where I am stuck and I cannot seem to figure out how or why this is happening. You can drag the items by the .handle (title element). I would appreciate any help as I seem to be stuck here.

Thanks for reading!

**Update**

It seems even if I put the .handle outside of the inner repeat, it still has the same problem. Perhaps it has to do with the order the inner repeat and the angulary packery run?

**Update 2**

It appears the drag handle logic is not working at all, you can drag by anything, not just .handle

**Update 3**

I am almost certain this has to do with the nested ng-repeat (perhaps it interacting in conjunction with how the directive runs on the object), because no matter what I try, as long as I have the nested repeat, I have the same issue. If I pull it off it goes back to working as normal, however It will be hard to achieve my desired goal without it :(.

Also - if i turn

```
var draggable2 = new Draggabilly(element[0], {handle: '.handle'} );
```

into

```
var draggable2 = new Draggabilly(element[0] );
```

It works fine. I need a drag handle though, as there will be content inside these divs the user will interact with, and I don't want the div moving around when they are clicking around inside it. *Maybe if there is a way to initiate dragabilly a little bit later?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it might be a digest issue, as if you stick the Draggabilly creation in a $timeout it works as expected

```
if(!isMobile()){
    $timeout(function(){
        var draggable2 = new Draggabilly(element[0], {handle: '.handle'} );
        $rootScope.packery.bindDraggabillyEvents(draggable2);
    })
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qxv1VWPHZEKX3pVHgBi2?p=preview

One thing of note i noticed whilst fiddling around with it, is if you use a different option than `handle`, for example `{ axis: 'x'}` then it works without the need for the `$timeout`.

Comment: I seriously cannot thank you enough, thank you for taking the time to dig through my pile of code and help!!

Comment: Yes here here for the code help.  Not only did you help him, you helped me, and you'll be helping people for years to come. james.patOnTheBacks += 1;